# Android app crashes due to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android-studio

I built and published an Android app, written in Java using Android Studio 2021.2.1 on a Mac.  The Play Store is reporting crashes.  Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3742)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4027)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2336)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:247)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8676)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (AppComponentFactory.java:95)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1253)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3730)
```

How do I fix this? I don't really know what to try because I'm new to Android development.

In case it helps, here's my AndroidManifest.xml (I've redacted some items with xxx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xxx"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.xxx"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: does your project has multidex enabled?

Comment: Usually behind the `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ` there is the class name of the class that is missing. If you launch the release build using Android Studio, does the app crash as well? Then you should find the class name in the stack trace from logcat, but it looks like it can't find your main Activity

Comment: No, my project does not have Multidex enabled.  

I'm unable to launch the release build using Android Studio because it comes up with: "Error: The apk for your currently selected variant cannot be signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant (release)."  

I can, however launch the Debug version in Android Studio but that dos not crash.